# emoji cannot be a literal and what else?

Tags: swift, literals

> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a type, such as a number or string

There are 3 kinds of literals in Swift: **Integer Literals**, **Floating-Point Literals** and **String Literals** (please correct me if I'm wrong), Is that means (**My Guess**) any elements which not belong to a type of Integer, Floating or String is not considered as a literal, and will trigger an error when used as literals

According to what I guess I've tried this `let aEmoji =`

[image]

**Question1:** Is my guess accurate? If not, I appreciate you could correct me.

**Question2:** Is there anything else shouldn't use as a literal? (would be nice you could give me some example)

Thanks

Comment: `true` and `false` (Boolean values) are also literals in Swift, as well as arrays, dictionaries, and probably a few others that I'm missing.

Comment: As well as the `nil` and character literal

Comment: @SLN You feel feel your qesution has been satisfied, please accept one of the answers.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Done ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, anything that isn't an integer literal (`1`), floating-point literal (`1.0`) or String literal (`"foo"`), Array literal (`[foo]`), Dictionary literal (`[foo : bar]`), bool literal (`true`/`false`) isn't a literal and would cause an error.
2. Anything that isn't one of the literals above isn't a literal, and could cause an error (if it's an invalid syntax).

You can make put an emoji in a string literal, however: `let aEmoji = ""`

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex ")

Answer (score 4):

A string literal is wrapped in double quotes

```
let aEmoji = ""
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> A string literal is a fixed sequence of textual characters
>   surrounded by a pair of double quotes ("").

Comment: Thx for the example

Answer (score 3):

You can include emojis in a literal String or Character expression by setting it off with double quotes.

The type inferrer will default the expression to a String literal, unless the `Character` type is specified.

```
let unicornString = ""
let unicornChar : Character = ""
```

Else the compiler will treat the emoji (or any unicode character sequence) as an identifier (because emoji can be variable names and such).

---

The following would be valid:

```
let  = "myPassword"
user.authenticateWithPassword()
```

Comment: oh.. That must be the reason why the compiler yield "Use of unresolved identifier" since it treat the smile emoji here as an identifier and of course I didn't declare it at all.